# "It would feel, or taste, a certain way to you to have that process going on in your brain"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> The view that the brain is the seat of consciousness, but that its
> conscious states are not just physical states, is called dual aspect
> theory. It is called that because it means that when you bite into a
> chocolate bar, this produces in your brain a state or process with two
> aspects: a physical aspect involving various chemical and electrical
> changes, and a mental aspect -- the flavor experience of chocolate.
> When this process occurs, a scientist looking into your brain will be
> able to observe the physical aspect, but you yourself will undergo,
> from the inside, the mental aspect: you will have the sensation of
> tasting chocolate. If this were true, your brain itself would have an
> inside that could not be reached by an outside observer even if he cut
> it open. **It** would feel, or taste, a certain way to you **to have that
> process going on in your brain**.

[Thomas Nagel, What does it all mean, Chapter IV]

Does the word "it" refer to "chocolate"?

I don't know the use of "to have" in "to have that process going on in your brain". Could you explain this to me?
I tried paraphrasing the sentence like this: "having that process going on in your brain would give you a certain feeling, or taste". Is it correct?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your paraphrase with "having that process..." is correct and it has the same meaning as "to have that process going on...".

The word "it" is a dummy pronoun that acts as the subject of the sentence. It refers to the to-infinitival clause that starts with "to have that process...".  That clause is called an extraposed subject. So, "it" doesn't refer to "chocolate".

[Thoughtco "extraposition"](https://www.thoughtco.com/extraposition-grammar-term-1690626)